# Should Properties/ServiceDependencies folder be ignored by source control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2022

Using Visual Studio 2022, I connected to a remote Azure App Services so I should be able to debug locally. After connecting, I saw that there were some auto generated files specifically under

- new folder `Properties/ServiceDependencies`
- new file `Properties/serviceDependencies.json`
- new file `Properties/serviceDependencies.local.json`

I'm not exactly sure why these files were added, but my question is, are these files needed just locally and should be ignored by source control?

Comment: Specific to your local development environment, should be ignored by source control.

Comment: thank you, any refrence docs for this?

Comment: [Configuring Azure Services and emulators using Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configuring-azure-services-and-emulators-using-visual-studio/)

Comment: local development environment are in every kind of projects a candidate for .gitignore

Comment: Good to know: .env, .env.development, and .env.production files should be included in your repository as they define defaults. .env*.local should be added to .gitignore, as those files are intended to be ignored. .env.local is where secrets can be stored. [Default Environment Variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#default-environment-variables)

Comment: u might as well put all this in an official answer ill mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The created documents and there settings are explained in the following devblog [Configuring Azure Services and emulators using Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configuring-azure-services-and-emulators-using-visual-studio/):

> To support all of this Visual Studio creates two new files visible in Solution Explorer under **Properties** called `serviceDependencies.json` and `serviceDependencies.local.json`. Both of these files are safe to check in as they do not contain any secrets.

In general, local development environment are in every kind of projects a candidate for "should be ignored by source control", like described here [Default Environment Variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#good-to-know):

> Good to know: .env, .env.development, and .env.production files should be included in your repository as they define defaults. .env*.local should be added to .gitignore, as those files are intended to be ignored. .env.local is where secrets can be stored.